# Wildcard Subdomain Setup on Windows 2003

Tags: windows, wildcard, subdomain

I am trying to setup an internal staging server for a web application that relies on wildcard subdomains.

I would appreciate some guidance in how to setup wildcard subdomains with Windows Server 2003 DNS.  (I don't seem to be able to enter "`*.domain.tld. IN A  1.2.3.4`" directly)

Thanks.

More information:

I have a zone `MY.LAN`,  under that I have a server (A record) `staging01`.  I want to setup up wildcard subdomains for staging01

Answer (score 2):

I've just checked and you can definately enter the wildcard entry directly into server 2003 DNS. Just go to new A record in the right zone, enter * in the name box and then enter the IP, works fine.

Comment: I was able to execute your instructions but was still unable to connect to the machine using a wildcard subdomain (i.e. it still recognizes stagin01 but not test.staging01)  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: If you ping the domain, what response do you get, the right IP?